# Add part of a website to my wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, html, iframe

I am trying to add a part of another website inside my wordpress.com website.
So I thought I would try iframe, but although this code would have worked on a regular website it doesn't seem to work in wordpress.com.

```
<div id="my-div" style="width: 400px; height: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
    <iframe id="my-iframe" style="position: absolute; top: -100px; left: -100px; width: 1280px; height: 1200px;" src="http://www.example.com/" width="300" height="150" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

In wordpress I just get `http://www.example.com/` as a result to this code.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<object data=http://www.example.com width=”650″ height=”500″> <embed src=http://www.example.com width=”650″ height=”500″> </embed></object>
```

Comment: You're changing the code inside `data="..."` and `src="..."` correct?

Comment: I would try maybe using a plugin dedicated to embedding content, per this plugin's page it seems like WordPress may disable the iframe tag for security reasons by default. https://wordpress.org/plugins/iframe/

Comment: Ye, sadly I think you are right. iframe (and every other way to embed) is disabled in wordpress.com. I also don't think I can add a plugin either. :/
Although I think I found a plugin under wordpress.org but not sure how and if I can connect it somehow with wordpress.com

Comment: How can I install the plugin you sent me at wordpress.com?